# Swift 4 AppStore like transition

Tags: swift

Trying to get this transition https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4TVnRx7PTTs

First VC has a card like image and second one is tableview with same image as sqare on first cell.

```
        let storyboard = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "vc2")

        let firstClassView = self.view
        let secondClassView = storyboard?.view


        secondClassView?.frame = self.card.frame

        if let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow {

            window.insertSubview(secondClassView!, aboveSubview: firstClassView!)

            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: { () -> Void in

                secondClassView?.frame = self.view.frame

            }, completion: {(Finished) -> Void in

               self.present(storyboard!, animated: false, completion: nil)

            })

        }
```

so i am adding the second vc's view to first vc with the frame of cardImage and animating it to full frame of a view. but the cardImage is not square so it doesn't look as good as app store. any suggestions?

Comment: found any solution?